# Get PID for running service

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-services

Is it possible to get PID of running service by PowerShell?

```
$srv = Get-Service MyTestService
$myPid = ... ?
```

Comment: You have to use get-Process and filter by name like this : get-process -Name Service* | Foreach { $_.Id }

Comment: @jdweng: The names of processes that run services can't be assumed to have the word "Service" in them, so this won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance) cmdlet with the `Win32_Service` WMI class:

```bash
# Obtain the service of interest.
$svc = Get-Service -ErrorAction Stop MyTestService

# Obtain its process ID (if any).
$svcPid = 
  (Get-CimInstance Win32_Service -Filter "Name = `"$($svc.Name)`"").ProcessId

# Obtain information about the process.
if ($svcPid) {
  Get-Process -Id $svcPid
} else {
  Write-Verbose -Verbose "Service `"$($svc.Name)`" isn't running."
}
```

Note that `$svcPid` will be `0` if the targeted service isn't running.